Overlay local image on D3 SankeyNetwork
I am trying to generate a Sankey Network with R, and would like to replace the nodes with images of the specific organisations.
I have some high resolution JPGs locally which are in the same project directory but I've had no luck editing it with htmlwidgets::onRender, and was hoping someone may have encountered something similar before.
Edit:
To add additional context I have added this code:
p <- htmlwidgets::onRender(p, '
    function(el, x) {
        d3.selectAll(".node")
        .filter(function (d) {return d.name.startsWith("organisationName")})
        .append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "organisation_logo.jpg")
    }
')

This half works, but the image is the broken image icon. Also tried with replacing svg with jpg in the append but no luck.
